# Error [Assetic\Exception\FilterException] Symfony Assetic with SASS Compass

Tags: symfony, compass-sass, assetic

I am trying to configure symfony assetic manager to compile my scss files and rewrite paths however I am getting the following error:

```
  [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
  An error occurred while running:
  '/usr/bin/ruby' '/usr/local/bin/sass' '--load-path' '/var/www/karta-otdyha/src/App/WebBundle/Resources/assets/scss' '--scss' '--style' 'compressed' '--cache-locati
  on' '/tmp' '--compass' '/tmp/assetic_sass463p4z'
  Error Output:
  TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Literal
    Use --trace for backtrace.
  Input:
...
  /*# sourceMappingURL=assetic_compassmpX1yk.css.map */
```

My config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug: %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: true
    bundles:        [ AppWebBundle ]
    ruby:           /usr/bin/ruby
    sass:           /usr/local/bin/sass
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scss:
            style: 'compressed'
            compass: true
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
        compass:
           images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/App/WebBundle/Resources/assets/images
           http_path: /bundles/appweb
           generated_images_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/App/WebBundle/Resources/public/images
           bin: /usr/local/bin/compass
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.9, Does anyone knows how could i fix it?